# How to Center two Jumbotrons in One Row in Bootstrap?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, center

I have two Jumbotrons in one row, but can't figure out how to center the row on the page. I'm assuming it's some simple CSS that I'm missing. Any suggestions for me?

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="well-lg">
  <div class="one">
    <div class="col-xs-6">
    <div class="jumbotron text-center">
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-xs ban-default">Button</a>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="two">
  <div class="col-xs-6">
  <div class="jumbotron text-center">
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-xs ban-default">Button</a>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

My current CSS shouldn't be messing with it but I'll post it anyway.

```
.one .jumbotron
{ background: url("IMG") no-repeat center center;
-webkit-background-size: 100% 100%;
-moz-background-size: 100% 100%;
-o-background-size: 100% 100%;
background-size: 100% 100%;
min-width: 220px;
max-width:240px;
height:290px;
}

.two .jumbotron
{ background: url("IMG") no-repeat center center;
    -webkit-background-size: 100% 100%;
    -moz-background-size: 100% 100%;
    -o-background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    min-width: 220px;
    max-width:240px;
    height:290px;
}
```

Comment: because you've overwritten bootstrap `.jumbotron` class! https://jsfiddle.net/Igor_Ivancha/pyqqwuus/

Comment: Any luck on solving this problem with the answers given so far? If so, please mark the question as solved.

Answer (score 0):

This is the simple exapmple of two jumbotrons:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="jumbotron">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-6">
                <h1>Bootstrap Tutorial</h1>
                <p>Bootstrap is the most popular HTML, CSS, and JS framework for developing responsive, mobile-first projects on the web.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-6">
                <h1>Bootstrap Tutorial</h1>
                <p>Bootstrap is the most popular HTML, CSS, and JS framework for developing responsive, mobile-first projects on the web.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1:** If I understood what you're trying to achieve here correctly, you want to remove the `max-width` value from your `.jumbotron` class entirely, just keep it at `100%`.

In order to size the jumbotron, you can adjust the `padding` in classes `.one` and `.two` to achieve a centered jumbotron.

Doing so, however, would be recommended to also switch up the place of your classes. Put `.one` and `.two` class divs in your HTML inside the columns to avoid unnecessary column padding.

**Solution 2:** If you would rather keep your max-width setup on `.jumbotron`, you can adjust the margin for your `.one` and `.two` classes. Just use `margin: 0 auto;` and it should center anything inside of it.

In this case, you should also switch up your custom class placing like I told on the first solution.

I hope this helps!

Answer (score -1):

Style your container class:
Add this code into your css file.

```
.container{
  position: absolute;
  margin: auto;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  }
```

check fiddle: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EPeLjV